# Check if a private function exists inside an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, private

How can I check if a private function exist inside an object?

```
var myObj = function(){
    var myFunc = function(){};

    var init = function(){
        //has myFunc been defined?
    }
}
```

I know that I can do this:

```
if (typeof myFunc == 'function') { 
    //myFunc exist
}
```

But this is checking the global scope.
How can I limit this to my objects scope?

Here is the most simplified case that i need:

```
var myComponent = function () {
    var exportExcel = function () {

    };
    this.export = function (type) {
        if('export'+type is a private function in this scope){
            window["export"+type]()//but in local scope;
        }
    }
};
```

And here is my work around for now :

```
var myComponent = function () {
    var Exports = {
        Excel: function () {

        }
    };

    this.export = function (type) {
        if (Exports.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
            Exports[type]();
        } else {
            alert('This Export type has not been implemented Yet ! or it never will ... how knows? well i don\'t ...');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you add a public method to check for the existence of a private one?

Comment: @elio.d This wouldn't tell if the function isn't defined in another intermediate scope (and btw you don't have to add a public function to know if there's a global myFunc).

Comment: The whole idea behind "private" functions is that you don't have access to them outside of the scope they're created in.

Comment: It is not checking the global scope, it is checking locally first, that's how lexical scope works. This looks like an XY problem... Why do you want to do this? What's the real-world application?

Comment: @DenysSéguret well the question does not mention any intermediate scope  so, and there's no mention to a global function, so your comment seems pointless

Comment: How are you calling `init` ?

Comment: @Cerbrus i am not accesing the private function from the outeside, i just want to check if a private function exist inside the object from another private function inside the same object

Comment: @DenysSéguret dose it matter?

Comment: @Exlord Yes, it totally matters. Depending on the call, there are trivial answers...

Comment: @elclanrs since it still checks the global scope too i cant know if mine exist or in the global scope... real world application would be something like php's magic getter/setters

Comment: You could do `if (myFunc && myFunc !== window.myFunc)` perhaps?

Comment: @Ja͢ck +1 but it does not deal with intermediate scopes right? Anyway Exlord, since you seem to be the writer of this code, you are supposed to know whether a private function is defined or not, why would you check then?

Comment: @wawawared well i don't want to change the `this.export` function body every time i add a new export function to the object

Comment: @Exlord Ok I got it. However your code seems to do the job :-| Looks like a self answered question :-)

Comment: @Exlord: I still think it is an XY problem. You are thinking in PHP but writing code in JavaScript. By real-world I mean what is the description of the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably noticed:

```
function myFunc () {};

function myObj () {
    function init () {
        if (myFunc) // passes
    };
}
```

You could cheat a bit :-|

```
function myObj () {
    var isdef = { myFunc: true };
    function myFunc () {};
    function init () {
        if (isdef.myFunc) // do something
    };
}
```

I wonder why one would do that though.

Comment: Well... he wants to check if it exists... it means he can't just change this line of code ^^

Comment: @DenysSéguret As long as you can edit the scope of `init` you should be able to edit the scope of `myObj` :-|

Comment: i already have :D , not like this but i defined my private function inside a private object and checked its `hasOwnProperty` :D

Comment: @Exlord `hasOwnProperty` is helpless in this case since you never define any property :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bases on the extra information given, the most practical pattern is what you're calling the "temporary workaround": keeping your functions in a private object, keyed by type.

```
var myComponent = function () {
    var exporters = Object.create(null, {
        "Excel": function () {
            // do magic export here
        }
    });

    this.export = function (type) {
        if (type in exporters) {
            // defined locally
            return exporters[type].call(this); // binding is optional
        } else {
            // no export for you!
        }
    }
};
```

This prevents two things:

1. Referencing the function via string composition,
2. Querying the global scope (or, actually, any scope in between your component and the global scope).

This may not be your design principle, you could further extend this code to allow for adding / removing exporters.

Comment: @Exlord Ah; well, that happens to be the most sensical solution as well :)